# Mutable alternative for std::string_view?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, c++17, string-view

Is there a mutable alternative to `std::string_view`?

I need a container that stores a pointer and a size e.g. for passing it to a function instead of passing a pointer *and* a size. I know it's easy enough to implement it myself; I just want to know if such a thing exists. I realy don't like using `std::vector` (or similar classes) because <s>they're resizable and</s> I want to avoid heap allocation as much as possible.

`std::array` uses a template parameter for size but I need something that stores the size so that I can wrap both static arrays and arrays on the heap or just part of an array; and I'm limited to C++17 so I can't use `std::span` (added in C++20) or `std::owning_view` (added in C++23).

Comment: `std::span` is the C++ standard library solution for this, so I doubt a C++17 version exists. Probably pointer+size is the best thing you can do, unless you can use another library like `gsl::span`

Comment: Is it so hard to define your own ad-hoc type?! If you can't use C++20, you can use raw pointers to define a class with a template constructor. Less than 20 lines, with proper spacing for readability.

Comment: I think it's introduced in c++20 is a pretty strong indication that it doesn't exist in c++17

Comment: btw resizable and heap allocation is not equal. (in both way)

Comment: @Red.Wave I could define it myself but I thought maybe something exists that has some Element Access/Modifier/Iterator/String Operation methods already implemented.

Comment: You can only modify characters with such an object. No insertions and no deletions. I'm curious what kind of application might need this kind of string view.